# Altium unrouted via

Tags: altium, via

I have placed two additional vias on the thermal pad of the IC. Though the datasheet does not specify thermal holes, but I just did them to connect the pad with the internal ground plane (2nd layer). I am not able to figure out, why altium claims that there is an error and the vias are not connected. Why shall I connect the vias with extra track? Are not they connected through the ground plane? Please help. This happens many times with me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the via's net

Comment: It's set to GND net

Comment: Are the vias set as "Plated"?

Comment: Yes @TomL. They are marked as plated.. I have added another screenshot

Comment: Not sure, but seems like the vias are not properly connected with Ground Plane (Layer 2) because of the thermal relief cutouts. I am a newbie, so might be wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

That was definitely the Pads were not connecting to the Ground Plane well due to the Thermal Cutouts. I had to disable the cutout by creating a new rule for such Pads and it seems the error is gone now :)